# Any physical expressions using the integral of the Bessel function of the Second Kind?

Tags: mathematical-physics

I am currently studying the asymptotic expansions of the integral of the form
$$
I(b)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \phi (x) Y_ \nu (bx) dx
$$
where $ \phi $ is an element of Schwartz space and $Y_ \nu $ is the Bessel function of the second kind.

My question is, are there any physical expression in the form of $I(b)$?

Comment: I don't really think my question will generate opinion-based answers, as I'm asking a very exact question. I just want to know if there are physics expressions, formulas, or equations in the form of $I(b)$.

Comment: See [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18468236#18468236) for a short discussion of this close reason. In essence, it's because it is a [tag:big-list], which is off-topic either way.